# Is "I am going for walking" right?

Tags: grammaticality

Every evening my friend appears at my door dressed up like Carl Lewis and announces "I am going for walking". I was wondering - is that expression right?

Comment: That is a regionalism you can see around the Indian subcontinent. In speech, *right* depends on the geography. A native BrE speaker may not express it exactly the same way as a native AmE speaker.

Comment: Sounds very much like substandard "Indian English" to me. [Here's](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=wq5lAAAAMAAJ&q=%22going+for+walking%22&dq=%22going+for+walking%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bcYbUYLvFoez0QXe74BY&ved=0CE4Q6AEwBQ) one of a handful of instances in Google Books... *Yes, I am knowing. He was **going for walking**. It was what he was very, very much liking. On his shoulders he would put what he was calling my good old knapsack.*

Comment: Was he trying to look like a walking Carl Lewis rather than a running Carl Lewis?

Answer (score 2):

It's usually said as "I am going walking' or 'going for a walk."

Comment: Where is it *usually* said?

Comment: Both that I've listed above are said in Australia.

Comment: And in the US and Canada and European countries whose residents learn British English. "I am going for walking" is strictly Indian English, not idiomatic American English. Which means that's it's "correct" in India and, perhaps, neighboring countries whose residents speak a similar brand of English.

Comment: Not used in British Standard English.

Comment: The aussie expression I have heard is _going walkabout_ but that is longer than a walk ;)

Comment: Yes, going 'walkabouts' is often used to mean people who may have no home, so wander a lot, walk a long way in a day.